# To swap or create new references?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Below is a simple bfs code

```
private void bfsTraveral() {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The root cannot be null.");
        }

        Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<TreeNode> queueNext = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(root);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            TreeNode node = queue.poll();
            System.out.println(node.element);
            if (node.left != null) queueNext.add(node.left);
            if (node.right != null) queueNext.add(node.right);

            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                queue = queueNext;
                queueNext = new LinkedList<>();
            }
        }
    }
```

My questions is about the piece of code that deals when queue is empty. 
It creates a new Queue `queueNext = new LinkedList<>();`.
My question is - is it good practice to swap rather than create new objects ? If yes why ? Note, that in the code above, GC should deal with null references and we dont leak memory.

Replacement code:

```
 if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                    Queue temp = queue;
                    queue = queueNext;
                    queueNext = temp;
                }
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need two separate queues?

Comment: feel code looks cleaner

Comment: Well, you can use a single queue and get rid of the unnecessary emptiness check with swapping/new objects.

Comment: As for your question, the only practical difference is a call to `LinkedList()` constructor. Overhead, if exists, is miniscule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the answer depends on the context of the application.  There's not enough context in the question to give you a 100% answer either way.

In your example, creating a new queue is more readable and maintainable code than swapping queues.  For someone new to the code (or if you're looking at it months later), it's easier to read that you're using a new queue from scratch as opposed having to figure what you're doing with the Queue temp swap-a-roo.  If you are confident in the garbage collection, memory leaks, etc., and performance (memory or speed) is not an issue then I would create a new queue.

On the other hand, if performance is an issue, then you might use the swap.  This is especially important on platforms with limited memory and/or really high real-time performance demands where memory fragmentation might impact speed.  For example, in traditional game development memory usage was at a premium, so it's common to see clever re-use of objects rather than creation/destruction of objects.  For example, game entities are often initialized out of pre-allocated pools.  Or one might use a ring buffer instead of creating/destroying new buffers on the fly.  In your example, you might pre-allocate queues of a certain size (i.e. establish a stable memory footprint up front) and then manipulate them in the traversal.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your comment about memory fragmentation (all that it entails) is not really pertinent to Java. The way in which the default implementation of the GC works means that heap fragmentation is kept to a minimum without significant effort. In fact, preallocation of memory can negatively impact performance if they are later discarded and new objects created. This is because the old objects gain tenure and moved to an area of memory that is only GCed in the most dire situations.

Comment: @Dunes thanks for the clarification on Java GC -- definitely not a strong suit of mine.